# Intercept deletion of element from ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a way where I can hook into removal of an element attached to an ngRepeat. I am doing this in order to add some animations. For the addition of the element it is easy enough to use the 'link' event, which is called when it is first created. I don't know how to intercept the removal event. Essentially I'd like to do the DOM removal myself.

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.1.4 ?  It has animations built in. So it should be easy to hook in animations to all the components.

Comment: Still using 1.0.1, and honestly, the animation system for 1.1.4 does not look promising.

Comment: There is no easy way to do animation in 1.0.x which is why they did the 1.1.4.. Unless you want to write your own repeaters ( which is not easy trust me! )... Whats wrong with 1.1.4? Maybe you could leave some feedback for people to improve upon?

Comment: I'm just going from the rather scarce docs and examples. I suppose I'll install it and see what is easier.

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Yes, that's the guide I'm trying to use... I've got some basics working, but now I've lost some features I had using the old technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell when the element is being deleted by subscribing to the `$destroy` event on the scope:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {...});
```

I'm not sure if you could take over removal of the element yourself, but maybe you could clone the element and manipulate the clone (like jQuery does with draggables).

Comment: Doesn't $destroy run after the DOM element has already been removed? You can't put animations on an element that no longer exists.